# Split a row into multiple rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to split a row into multiple rows based on some value in a cell? Here's an example

Say I have one row like below

A,B,C,D1 - 5 D2 - 16 D3 - 27,E

I want to split this into three rows (note that I'm removing specific values from the fourth cell)

A,B,C,D1,E

A,B,C,D2,E

A,B,C,D3,E

Added a screenshot as reference - blue is what it is now and yellow is what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: did you found a solution? I have similar question and want same result. Please post your solution, if you found any. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Merge all of the columns together, then use the text to columns wizard to split out the value you wish to remove

[Microsoft guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7#:%7E:text=You%20can%20take%20the%20text,the%20Delimiters%20for%20your%20data.)

Comment: This doesn't split it because the length varies

Comment: How many variations of length are there, and how many rows need to be processed?

Comment: I added a screenshot to show what I need to achieve. The only consistent part is that every string starts with an X but there may be many.

Comment: @JavaChipMocha did you found a solution? I have similar question and want same result. Please post your solution, if you found any. Thank you!